Salesforce Control Dependent Field based on Record Type
Though its 2024, still struck with some limitations of SF I believe.
I have 2 Case recordTypes Carload and Asset.
a controlling field Category with below values

Billing
Customs etc

A Dependant field Reason with below values

Invoice etc

Invoice should be available for Billing but not for Customs (This can be achieved via field dependency but...) if the recordtype is Carload.
But If its Asset RecordType, Invoice should be available for Customs.
Current Config:

Field Dependency to include Invoice for Customs and Billing (Since one of the recordtype needs this dependency)
Carload RecordType Picklist 'Reason' to include Invoice (since its used by different controlling field though)

how can I achieve this? (without validation Rule)
